# Get all Files in a directory throws error - Cannot dynamically create an instance of type 'Photobx.Pages.Index'. No parameterless constructor defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to do an "image gallery" in my Blazor Server App. For each Filepath it should create an `<img src="@file"/>` element containing the filepath in the local variable "file".

Now it throws me this error: `MissingMethodException: Cannot dynamically create an instance of type 'Photobx.Pages.Index'. Reason: No parameterless constructor defined.`

My files are in wwwroot/pics .

Here is my code:

index.razor

```
@foreach(string file in filepaths)
{
    <img src="@file"/>
}

@code {
    private IWebHostEnvironment Environment;
    public List<string> filepaths = new List<string>();

    public Index(IWebHostEnvironment _environment)
    {
        Environment = _environment;
    }

    public void GetFilePaths()
    {
        foreach(string file in Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(this.Environment.WebRootPath, "pics/")))
        {
            filepaths.Add(file);
            Console.WriteLine(file + " was added");
        }
    }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        GetFilePaths();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot inject parameters to a Blazor component from the constructor.

You can use the `@inject` razor directive

```
@inject IWebHostEnvironment Environment

@foreach(string file in filepaths)
{
    <img src="@file"/>
}
...
```

or `[Inject]` attribute when using code-behind approach.

```
public class ComponentBase : IComponent
{
    [Inject]
    protected IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; set; }
}
```

Check [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0#request-a-service-in-a-component) for more information regarding this topic.